# How do I import the fft2d in tensorflow 2.0.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, fft, tensorflow2.0

I want to use the [`fft2d` function of `tensorflow` 2.0.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/fft2d).
In 1.14.0, I could just do the following:

```py
from tensorflow.signal import fft2d
```

In 2.0.0, I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.signal'`.

I can however do:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.signal.fft2d
```

However, I feel that it is a bit heavy, I would like to just use `fft2d`. Why can't I use the previous method anymore?

Comment: I opened a Github question to draw more attention to this problem, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35545. The issue has been reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing signal in Tensorflow 2.0 can be done in a way given below.

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.signal.fft_ops import fft2d, ifft2d
```

For more info please refer to the following [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/ops/signal/signal.py) and also the following [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/gowthamkpr/c546437c5202514615276c3bd4e83edc/35545.ipynb).

I am [closing this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35545) as it has been resolved.